# What does `for a[x] in a` mean in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to understand the weird behavior of the below code. How can I understand the below output? I think it should print 3 3 3 3, but it's printing the below output.

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
for a[3] in a:
    print(a[3])
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 2
```

Comment: I have been writing python for 10 years and have never seen code like this. Please do not assume this is normal python code. In python, it is considered best practice to write clear code that is easy to understand - this code does not meet that criteria.

Answer (score 3):

`for a[3] in a:` successively assigns elements of `a` to the its last element:

- 1st iteration, `a[3]` becomes `a[0]` which is `0` >> prints  `0`
- 2nd iteration, `a[3]` becomes `a[1]` which is `1` >> prints  `1`
- 3rd iteration, `a[3]` becomes `a[2]` which is `2` >> prints  `2`
- 4th iteration, `a[3]` becomes `a[3]` (so stays unchanged) which is `2` >> prints  `2`

Answer (score 1):

When you use a same variable name in for loops it can override the current value, in your case the `a[3]` will be presents instead of each item of the `a` list, now when the current index become `3` it writes the actual `a[3]` value that is `2`. 
for better understanding :

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
for a[2] in a:
    print(a[2])
```

output: 0 1 1 3

Comment: does it also mean it would modify the original list.